# There are surprisingly few information about the asymptote package..... what do i do after i download it? Is it a package for LaTeX?

Tags: asymptote

[image]

Ive opened it i i get this...... do i type stuff inside？ Or.......what should i do with it? Im  very new to asyptote actually   Or cn anybody reccomend me any sites or videos to get me started? I visited every single one I could but to no avail 
For example, reading this:
[image]

how do i create a test file named test.asy? How do i execute the command asy-V test?  Help haha

Comment: I haven't used asymptote much other than a couple of tests so I won't answer, but `texdoc asymptote` opens a 189 page manual  in texlive, and the same will be in miktex.

Comment: Like it's written in the tut. Create a text file and type in `draw((0,0)--(100,100));` save it as test.asy in the same directory as your asy batch. Now type `asy -V test` and you will get an eps file. If you like to have an pdf you type `asy -V -f pdf test`

Comment: Was that..... English haha Are you providing help to me finding a users manual?

Comment: Tutorial that starts at the beginning: http://math.uchicago.edu/~cstaats/Charles_Staats_III/Notes_and_papers_files/asymptote_tutorial.pdf

Comment: Stupid question over here  please dont kill me      how do i open a text file? I seriously do not know

Comment: If you've already got TeX installed, use the editor that comes with TeX, and save with an .asy extension.  If not, it depends on what operating system your computer runs on.  notepad on windows, textedit on mac, emacs on linux.

Comment: @Andrew Kepert do i have to do all the \begin{document} and stuff like that?

Comment: Concerning the `\begin{document}`: Did you read the tutorial? Subsection 1.2 provides a simple "Hello World" example and states "She uses her favorite text editor to produce a document consisting of
the single line [...] and saves it as `hello_world.asy`".

Comment: Your screenshot looks like Windows 7, is that correct? If so, you can look for example at https://www.wikihow.com/Open-Notepad how to open the default windows text editor. There you can type the example code that you find in the tutorial that @AndrewKepert suggested. After you type the example code, you press the File menu on the top of the Notepad window and you press Save. Then you go to the command prompt, see https://www.digitalcitizen.life/7-ways-launch-command-prompt-windows-7-windows-8. Then in the command prompt you go to the directory where you saved your file ...

Comment: ... see https://www.digitalcitizen.life/command-prompt-how-use-basic-commands. Then you can run the `asy` commands as in the tutorial (page 4 and further).